# Lodash defaultTo recursive parent checking

Tags: javascript, json, lodash

I'm trying to default a long JSON object like `app.data.user.post.id`. The thing is that `user` does not have to exist (or any parent), in which case -1 has to be returned.

When I try `_.defaultTo(app.data.user.post.id, -1)` I get the expected error "could not get property 'post' from undefined".

I know this is doable by checking each and every parent along the way, but I'm wondering is there is a more elegant way to do this.

Comment: `app.data.user` is `undefined`.

Comment: Yes, @evolutionxbox, that could be the case. I'd like to know the most optimal way to default an undefined parent to -1 (or some static value).

Comment: You could try `(app.data.user || {}).post`

Comment: @Ryad in that case I'd get "could not get property 'id' from undefined", in which case i have to do a lot more comparisons than just &&ing all individual parents (in case user exists and post doesn't)

Comment: Another option: `const value; try { value = app.data.user.post.id } catch (e) { value = -1 }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Lodash function [_.get](https://lodash.com/docs/#get) can be used to resolve the 'path' and can also take a default value:

```js
var app ={data: {user:null}} ;//.post.id
var res = _.get(app, 'data.user.post.id', -1);
console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It resolves and falls back, but doesn't assign `-1` to `app.data.user.post.id`.

Comment: @dfsq  Should it? The question doesn't seem to require that the value is written to the object.

Comment: I don't know, maybe not actually.

Comment: No it does not, this is what I was looking for! The string is not very elegant but better than a long piece of &&'s. Thanks!

Comment: @dfsq it would be dangerous to assign the default value; especially in a method named `get`. To assign the value `get` would have to build the path. This means building incomplete and therefore probably invalid `user` and `post` objects.